# IBM websphere application server not started in MyEclipse8.0

Tags: java, websphere, myeclipse

I hava downloaded and installed IBM Websphere Application Server6.0 and installed it.
I want to deploy my EJB application on Websphere server in MyEclipse8.0.
I have configured the server with the required fields.
Now when i am starting the Websphere server i am getting the following errors...

```
websphere6Server [Remote Java Application]  
com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher at localhost:2747   
    Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        URL.<init>(URL, String, URLStreamHandler) line: 504 
        URL.<init>(URL, String) line: 462   
        URL.<init>(String) line: 411    
        XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(String, XMLInputSource, boolean, boolean) line: not available   
        XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLInputSource) line: not available  
        XML11Configuration.parse(boolean) line: not available   
        XML11Configuration.parse(XMLInputSource) line: not available    
        SAXParser(XMLParser).parse(XMLInputSource) line: not available  
        SAXParser(AbstractSAXParser).parse(InputSource) line: not available 
        MBeanDescriptorLoader2.load(InputStream, String) line: 156  
        MBeanDescriptorManager.loadMasterDescriptorFile(String) line: 374   
        MBeanDescriptorManager.<init>() line: 96    
        MBeanFactoryImpl.<init>(String) line: 92    
        AdminServiceImpl.<init>() line: 156 
        AdminImpl.initialize(Object) line: 177  
        ServerImpl(ContainerImpl).initializeComponent(String, Object, ComponentManager, Map, List, ConfigLocator[], ContainerImpl$ComponentStartup) line: 1161  
        ServerImpl(ContainerImpl).initializeComponents(EObject, ConfigLocator[]) line: 1015 
        ServerImpl.initialize(Object) line: 245 
        WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(Server, ContainerImpl, RepositoryImpl, ConfigLocator[], ComponentManager) line: 157    
        WsServerImpl.start(String, String, String, String) line: 120    
        WsServerImpl.main(String[]) line: 378   
        WsServer.main(String[]) line: 50    
        NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
        NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 85  
        NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Method, Object, Object[]) line: 58  
        DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Method, Object, Object[]) line: 60  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 391   
        WSLauncher.main(String[]) line: 190 
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin\javaw.exe (Apr 25, 2012 4:12:03 PM)
```

...........................................

will anyone please help me out of this problem. i'll be very thank full to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try starting the server form the command line and ensure that it works before trying to start it from inside Eclipse?

HTH

Manglu